# Check paypal donation thought API access

Tags: api, paypal, restful-architecture, donations

Reading almost the whole API reference of paypal, i am almost sure that they do not provide any kind of API method regarding donations. However i would like to check whether someone donates something to my paypal account and get some details of this transaction.

I thought of using the [Activities Search REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/activities/), however it was responding with -> "No permission for the requested operation" while i was testing it with my sandbox business account.

Anyone got any idea of how to claim this details? Do i missing something?

My last thought, was to use gmail API's to read the incoming emails that i am receiving (from paypal) when i got a donation, however i believe it's not a good solution, so its my last choice.

Comment: I have the same problem. do u have news?